# How to sort the month which is a string in SQL by months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have a big query that is returining results as I needed from a temp table, and I also have a big query that fills data in temp table.

Now the problem is, in final result, I am doing

datename(month,#ClaimsByBenefitCode.CalendarYear)

Hence, I reckon, it outputs as string? I get the alphabetical order. How to do it monthly?

For example, it shows October first and then September, but I want September first and then October. However, wanna ensure it doesn't have any side effects.

Any clue please?

Comment: put `ORDER BY DATEPART(mm,#ClaimsByBenefitCode.CalendarYear)` at the end of your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you have an `order by` clause that is something like this:

```
order by datename(month, #ClaimsByBenefitCode.CalendarYear)
```

You can fix this in several ways.  One is:

```
order by datepart(month, #ClaimsByBenefitCode.CalendarYear)
```

If this is an aggregation query, you can also do:

```
order by min(#ClaimsByBenefitCode.CalendarYear)
```

Comment: Oh Gordon, are you the GOD? You were more fast to even understand my scenario which is aggregation, and your last line worked for me like magic, I was thrilled. Man if I have knowledge like you in SQL, I will make a very good freelancing business too. Great to speak to you, thank you for helping me :) :) Just confirming, I didn't had orderby earlier, but upon your guidance, I added, it works, but hope it won't have any side effects? Please tell me

Comment: SELECT DATENAME(year,#ClaimsByBenefitCode.CalendarYear) as Year, datename(month,#ClaimsByBenefitCode.CalendarYear) as Month,
  #ClaimsByBenefitCode.BenefitCode as 'Benefit Code', sum(#ClaimsByBenefitCode.VolumeOfClaims) as 'Volume Of Claims'
  FROM #ClaimsByBenefitCode
  group by DATENAME(year,#ClaimsByBenefitCode.CalendarYear), datename(month,#ClaimsByBenefitCode.CalendarYear), 
  #ClaimsByBenefitCode.BenefitCode
        order by min(#ClaimsByBenefitCode.CalendarYear)

Comment: @Divine . . . Whenever you want results in a particular order, you should always use `order by`.  *Never* depend on the results coming from a query and what they "look" like.

Comment: Gordon, yeah, I am aware, but I tried to do the same, but didn't include "MIN" keyword. But could you please explain what does MIN keyword do magically to get the result I wanted?

Comment: Ok I will read about min keyword. I think it does the same job of datepart but when in aggregation

Comment: If you don't include `MIN()` then you would likely get an error that `CalendarYear` in not in the `group by` clause.  Then you would include it in the `group by`, and get more rows than you are expecting.  That, at least, is a common scenario when working with dates like this.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon...It helps me :)